# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression: Calling function in a return statement

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function

I am fairly new to React and I am currently having this issue.
Background info of my code: Suggestion is a child component of a `<datalist>`, so I want to return all the options possible. The Suggestions component has `props.songRec` which is an array of songs information that I want to fill in each option. I want to assign the text value returned from the function toText but there is this problem "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" on the `<option></option>` line.

```
function Suggestion(props) {
  console.log(props.songRec);

  const toText = (song) => {
    var text = song.name + " - ";
    const artistList = song.artists;
    for (var j = 0; j < artistList.length; j++) {
      if (j === artistList.length - 1) text += artistList[j].name;
      else text += artistList[j].name + " & ";
    }
    console.log(text);
    return text;
  }

  return (
    <> {props.songRec.map(song => {
      <option value={toText(song)}></option>
    })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I realized the mistake pointed out by @nibble and thank you Dave for pointing that I didn't return explicitly.

Comment: Since you wrapped the arrow function body with a `{}` you'll need an explicit return.

Comment: The options are not returned inside the `songRec` map.

Comment: You are in a functional component. `this` is used in class components. It is `props.songRec.map()` not `this.props.songRec.map()`